# how to fix the issue jsruntime is null?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

When I try to call a JSRuntime method from a component, an exception is thrown. These are my components:

**component1.razor**

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark ms-2" @onclick="(async()=> await comp.Function(data))">
    show
</button>

@code{
    Component2 comp= new component2();
}
```

**component2.razor**

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@code{
    public async Task Function(List<string> data)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("function-name", "id", data);
    }
}
```

**This is the exception**

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'jsRuntime')
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'JsRuntime')
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice this line in your codes:

```
Component2 comp= new component2();
```

The instance of Component2 is created by yourself ,not through DI,so it couldn't get the required parameter `JsRuntime` from the DI container and caused the ArgumentNullException

If you want to reduce duplicated codes,create a shared class:

```
public class SharedJsModule
 {
     private readonly IJSRuntime _JSRuntime;
     public SharedJsModule(IJSRuntime JSRuntime)
     {
         _JSRuntime = JSRuntime;
     }

     public async Task Function(List<string> data)
     {
         await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("function-name", "id", data);
     }
 }
```

register it :

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<SharedJsModule>();
```

and inject it into both of your components:

```
@inject SharedJsModule SharedJs
```